# HTML Input allow only Integers and Delete key

Tags: javascript, html

In reference to this question: [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

with one possible solution:

```html
 
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'></input>
```

I wonder if it's also possible to have this solution (I'm looking for a one line statement, nothing else) adapted, such that it permits, besides for all integers, also for the delete key (and possibly backspace key) to be able to be pressed? So that a number which was inserted can be erased again.

Many thx!

Comment: The solution is already on the link you posted (though it is in JQuery, which sucks a bit). It can't be a single statement, and it shouldn't.

Comment: Note that the "solution" doesn't prevent entering values other than numbers, so doesn't work in that regard.

Comment: @RobG Thx for the comment, but how do u conclude that? For me, using this, I can't insert anything else than integers between 0 and 9?

Comment: @Tim—you can paste any value you like, or drag text into the input.

Comment: @RobG True I haven't checked that, thx! Anyway, this "solution" is good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some browsers, Backspace and Delete will not trigger onkeypress. In other browsers, backspace and delete have charCode 0, so try this:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return !event.charCode || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)'/>
```

Comment: Thx, that should do the job!